# Popen always run, ignoring the if

Tags: python

I want that when I respond other thing diferent that yes, the subprocess don't run.

```
r = raw_input('\nDo you want play the video?\n\nY:Yes  N:No\n\n')
if r == "Y" or "y" or "yes" or"yep" or"yeah":
    message("Playing Video")
    subprocess.Popen(playvid)
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
if r == "Y" or "y" or "yes" or"yep" or"yeah":
```

to

```
if r in ["Y","y","yes","yep","yeah"] :
```

or change your response to lower case

```
r = raw_input('\nDo you want play the video?\n\nY:Yes  N:No\n\n').lower()
if r in ["y","yes","yep","yeah"] :
```

Comment: probably Alquimista also can do like
r.lower() in ["Y","y","yes","yep","yeah"] :

:-)

Comment: @shahjapan: if you're using lower() then why include `"Y"` on the list?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but I believe the issue is your syntax in this line:

```
if r == "Y" or "y" or "yes" or"yep" or"yeah":
```

You are testing the truth of "Y", "y", etc, which all evaluate to "true". Put all of the values in a sequence and do:

```
if r in seq:
```

That should be a much cleaner way to do it than

```
if r == "Y" or r == "y"...
```

Comment: Small correction: `==` binds tighter than `or`, so the OP is testing the truth of `(r=="Y") or "y" or "yes"` etc.